# PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'sequence_name' not allowed in this context

Tags: plsql, oracle-11g

Buen día.!

Tengo un problema con el reinicio de una sequence.

```
declare
  val number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select ' || SEQ_PRUEBA_1.nextval || ' from dual' into val;
  execute immediate 'alter sequence' || SEQ_PRUEBA_1 || ' INCREMENT BY ' - val;
  execute immediate 'select ' || SEQ_PRUEBA_1.nextval || ' from dual';
  execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || SEQ_PRUEBA_1 || ' INCREMENT BY 1';
end;
```

Me sale el siguiente error

`PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'SEQ_PRUEBA_1' not allowed in this context`

Por qué no lo permite y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia Select no ejecuta de esa manera dentro de un bloque. Ademas de que modifique un poco la logica, ya que presentarías un problema; dejabas la secuencia en un numero negativo y al consultarla el "last_number" no puede ser menor a 0....

te dejo aqui la correccion por si todavia buscas la solucion.

```html
declare
  val number;
begin
  SELECT PRUEBA_SEQ.nextval INTO val FROM DUAL;
  val:= val -1;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE PRUEBA_SEQ  INCREMENT BY -'|| val;
  SELECT PRUEBA_SEQ.nextval INTO val FROM DUAL;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE PRUEBA_SEQ  INCREMENT BY 1';
  
end;
```